# Correlation of different columns

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a huge Excel file, with several 100 columns. For example,  I want to correlate the first 10 columns with the next 10 columns, or any other column range. Whats the best way to do this. For example, with `df.iloc[:,0:10].corr()` I get the first 10 columns. Unfortunately, I do not know, how to go further than that.

Can you help me?

Comment: do you want to then add these new columns to the dataframe?

Comment: No, I just want to look at specific column areas of how well or poorly they correlate.

Comment: In your example, do you want to correlate the first column with the 11th, the second with the 12th and so on or all the first 10 with all the next 10 (1 with 11, 1 with 12, 1 with 13,...)?

Comment: I want to correlate the first 10 with the next 10 columns, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [`corr.with`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html) instead of `corr`. However, `corr.with` compares a *DataFrame* with a *Series* (df to df would be ambiguous pairings, so returns `NaN`). Therefore, consider running a list comprehension off a `range` of comparative columns to return a list of *Series* that can be then casted into a *DataFrame*. Below demonstrates with random seeded data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(61918)
# DATAFRAME OF 100 COLS AND 100 ROWS
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,100))

# CORRELATION BETWEEN FIRST 10 AND NEXT 10 COLUMNS 
# (ADJUST .iloc INDICES AND range FOR OTHER COLS)
corr_df = pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[:,0:10].corrwith(df.iloc[:,i], axis=0) for i in range(10,20)])
print(corr_df)

#           0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
# 0 -0.099616  0.052101 -0.089509 -0.053868  0.033873 -0.043973  0.044963 -0.012135 -0.021728 -0.052815
# 1 -0.111734  0.187650  0.104816  0.008250 -0.035936  0.002264  0.023941 -0.135608  0.081189 -0.073853
# 2  0.010684 -0.065890 -0.234728 -0.044789  0.042876 -0.114719 -0.073446 -0.185746  0.007169  0.158093
# 3  0.056081 -0.019951 -0.057006 -0.060794 -0.069991  0.039497  0.041345  0.018930 -0.056765 -0.128366
# 4  0.234364 -0.202907  0.039083 -0.017380 -0.020491 -0.126441  0.033971 -0.088621 -0.011655 -0.007285
# 5  0.010350 -0.160066 -0.141838  0.083785 -0.125714 -0.007721  0.082826 -0.207254 -0.064831 -0.036318
# 6  0.007275 -0.004525 -0.086660 -0.070298  0.024023 -0.087400 -0.029985  0.042614 -0.058841  0.035254
# 7  0.030607 -0.101061  0.004954  0.092204 -0.005586  0.041793  0.067349 -0.003554  0.050511 -0.039119
# 8 -0.061966 -0.198703 -0.011631 -0.028350  0.021107  0.160191  0.087607 -0.032543 -0.025399  0.005975
# 9 -0.053608  0.079021 -0.068879  0.005653 -0.040717 -0.030002 -0.008213 -0.005511 -0.052635  0.176989
```